# Keras seems to hang after call to fit_generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to fit the Keras implementation of the [SqueezeDet model](https://github.com/omni-us/squeezedet-keras) to a new dataset.  After making the appropriate changes to my config file, I tried to run the train script, but it seems to hang after the call to `fit_generator()`.  As I get the following output:

```
/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Using TensorFlow backend.
Number of images: 536
Number of epochs: 100
Number of batches: 53
Batch size: 10
2018-07-04 14:18:49.711606: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2018-07-04 14:18:54.080912: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1356] Found device 0 with properties:
name: Tesla K80 major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.8235
pciBusID: 52a9:00:00.0
totalMemory: 11.17GiB freeMemory: 11.10GiB
2018-07-04 14:18:54.080958: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1435] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-07-04 14:18:54.333214: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:923] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-07-04 14:18:54.333270: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:929]      0
2018-07-04 14:18:54.333290: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:942] 0:   N
2018-07-04 14:18:54.333559: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 10764 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 52a9:00:00.0, compute capability: 3.7)
Learning rate: 0.01
Weights initialized by name from ../main/model/imagenet.h5
Using single GPU
Backend Qt5Agg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
Epoch 1/100
```

And then nothing happens even if it leave it alone for a day.  The call that it seems to freeze on is:

```
squeeze.model.fit_generator(train_generator, epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=1,
                            steps_per_epoch=nbatches_train, callbacks=cb)
```

Where the parameters are:

```
train_generator = generator_from_data_path(img_names, gt_names, config=cfg)
EPOCHS = 100
nbatches_train  = 53
callbacks = [# TensorBoard object, ReduceLROnPlateau object, ModelCheckpoint object #]
```

My versions:

```
Python 3.5.4 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)
tensorflow-gpu : 1.8.0
tensorflow : 1.8.0
Keras : 2.2.0
```

Comment: Remove the TensorBoard callback and try again.

Comment: Does `train_generator[0]`return anything? Does `len(train_generator)` return anything?

Comment: @wl2776 Doesn't work since train_generator is a `threadsafe_iter` object `train_generator[0] > TypeError("'threadsafe_iter' object does not support indexing",)` and `len(train_generator) > TypeError("object of type 'threadsafe_iter' has no len()",)`.  However I think you are on to something, if I try and access the first element using `next(train_generator)` it hangs on that line instead.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Removing the callback makes no difference.

Comment: Ok, then you should add more information (code), like what is train_generator.

Comment: Since `train_generator` uses `threading.Lock`, I would suppose, it somehow falls into a deadlock. Try to debug it. I've moved from similar generators to subclasses of `keras.utils.Sequence`

Comment: @wl2776 Thank you for the help, it turns out my bounding box file was formatted improperly so it wasn't able to read any in.  If you want to post an answer (particularly explaining how you knew to look at the train_generator) I will select it.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy What made you say removing TensorBoard callback will fix the problem? I am working on [Mask RCNN](https://github.com/zekeriyyaa/MaskRCNN-Modanet-Fashion-Segmentation-and-Classification) and facing the same problem. There is a TensorBoard callback in this model as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Formatting conversation in comments to answer.

The culprit was `train_generator`.

I have looked into sources of `model.fit_generator` in Keras some time ago. It just retrieves some data from the generator and submits it to the backend, nothing magical :)

So, my hypothesis was that it cannot retrieve data from the generator because the generator does not generate anything.

@Barker has confirmed it, stating that call to `next(train_generator)` hangs.

I personally have moved to `keras.utils.Sequence` that supports indexing and length and is much more convenient than ordinary generators. Though this note is not related to the current problem.

Comment: Additionally, `keras.utils.Sequence` is thread-safe, and that's a huge plus.