# fit_generator hangs on first step in R

Tags: r, keras, deep-learning

Trying to run the temperature forecasting problem from [Deep Learning in R.](https://jjallaire.github.io/deep-learning-with-r-notebooks/notebooks/6.3-advanced-usage-of-recurrent-neural-networks.nb.html) When I get to the section "A basic machine learning approach," running the fit_generator function below causes R to hang indefinitely.

```
history <- model %>% fit_generator(
  train_gen,
  steps_per_epoch = 500,
  epochs = 20,
  validation_data = val_gen,
  validation_steps = val_steps
)
```

This is the only output I get, and it doesn't look like GPU is working on anything:

```
2020-06-10 11:18:15.459654: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
Epoch 1/20
  1/500 [..............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0249
```

I tried running the parallel code in Python from [this notebook](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/6.3-advanced-usage-of-recurrent-neural-networks.ipynb) and it ran smoothly, so I'm guessing it has something to do with R's version of Keras not being able to handle generator functions correctly.

I saw something about turning off multi-threading/processing [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51176661/keras-seems-to-hang-after-call-to-fit-generator). There is no `use_multiprocessing` in R; there is a `workers` argument that sounds similar, but it's already defaulted to 1. So it's unlikely to be this too. Pretty much at a dead end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a known issue, please refer to https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/1090

One of the solutions that sometimes works is to wrap original generator from R with `keras:::as_generator.function` function:

```
data_generator_py <- keras:::as_generator.function(data_generator)
```