# Mask-RCNN Training gets stuck at the beginning

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

My model seems to be stuck at the beginning of the training process by using the forked [Mask-RCNN-TF2.7.0-keras2.8.0](https://github.com/Kamlesh364/Mask-RCNN-TF2.7.0-keras2.8.0). There is no error so I am unable to know why. I find that many people have encountered this problem on the official Mask_RCNN (see [#2168](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/issues/2168), [#1899](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/issues/1899), [#1962](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/issues/1962)).

They have mainly provided two solution:

1. set `workers = 0`, and `use_multiprocessing = False`, which I found that you have already done in the source file `model.py`;
2. update the GPU driver. My current GPU driver version is 512.15, which I suppose is quite new.

Some people say that the code can work fine in ubuntun system, but not on windows 10. Well, this is the same thing for me, but I haven't found any solution yet. By the way, my training dataset contains only 20 images, so it should not be so difficult to train it.

**The code that I run into problem is as follow, which is basically the same as the sample `train_shapes.ipyb` provided by Matterport team.**

```
#### create Mask_RCNN model ####
model = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode='training', config=config, model_dir=MODEL_DIR) # Define the model

# Which weights to start with?
init_with = 'coco'  # coco, or last
ly_names=['mrcnn_class_logits', 'mrcnn_bbox_fc', 
'mrcnn_bbox', 'mrcnn_mask']
# ly_decodes=[unicode(s) for s in ly_names]

if init_with == 'coco':
    # %debug
     
    model.load_weights(COCO_MODEL_PATH, by_name=True,
                      exclude=ly_names)
elif init_with == 'last':
    model.load_weights(model.find_last(), by_name=True) # model.find_last()

#### Train the model layers ####
# Train the head layers
model.train(dataset_train, dataset_val,
            learning_rate=config.LEARNING_RATE, 
            epochs=1, # epoch=60 in original verison
            layers='heads',
            augmentation=augmentation)

# Fine-tune all layers
model.train(dataset_train, dataset_val, 
            learning_rate=config.LEARNING_RATE / 10,
            epochs=1, # epoch=140 in original version
            layers='all',
            augmentation=augmentation)

#### create a config instance used for inference ####
class InferenceConfig(Config):
    GPU_COUNT = 1
    IMAGES_PER_GPU = 1
    
    IMAGE_MAX_DIM = 1024
    IMAGE_MIN_DIM = 1024
    
    IMAGE_RESIZE_MODE = 'square'

inference_config = InferenceConfig()
batch_size = inference_config.BATCH_SIZE

#### load the last training weight for inference ####
model = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode="inference", 
                          config=inference_config,
                          model_dir=MODEL_DIR)

model.load_weights(model.find_last(), by_name=True) # 72
```

**When I run the above code, all I can get is this:**

```
Starting at epoch 0. LR=0.001

Checkpoint Path: C:\Mask_RCNN2.0\logs\trout20220520T1216\mask_rcnn_trout_{epoch:04d}.h5
Selecting layers to train
fpn_c5p5               (Conv2D)
fpn_c4p4               (Conv2D)
fpn_c3p3               (Conv2D)
fpn_c2p2               (Conv2D)
fpn_p5                 (Conv2D)
fpn_p2                 (Conv2D)
fpn_p3                 (Conv2D)
fpn_p4                 (Conv2D)
rpn_model              (Functional)
mrcnn_mask_conv1       (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_bn1         (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_conv2       (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_bn2         (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_class_conv1      (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_class_bn1        (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_conv3       (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_bn3         (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_class_conv2      (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_class_bn2        (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_conv4       (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_bn4         (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_bbox_fc          (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_deconv      (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_class_logits     (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask             (TimeDistributed)
C:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\CNNTest2\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizer_v2\gradient_descent.py:102: UserWarning: The `lr` argument is deprecated, use `learning_rate` instead.
  super(SGD, self).__init__(name, **kwargs)
```

**My environment setup is**

- GPU: NVIDIA Quadro P620, 2GB (maybe it is too small for Mask_RCNN training??)
- CUDA Driver API: 11.6
- CUDA Runtime API: 11.2
- cuDNN: 8.1
- tensorflow 2.7.0
- Keras 2.7.0 (changed due to the [previous problem](https://github.com/Kamlesh364/Mask-RCNN-TF2.7.0-keras2.8.0/issues/4))
- OS: windows 10

Is there any version incompatible for my setup? Or some other problems?
Many thanks if you can help me with it.

Best,

Erin

**Here I add the traceback info when I interrupt the process when using CPU training (hang at epoch 1/10).**

```
 File C:\Mask_RCNN2.0\trout\FishSeg_0520.py:325 in <module>
    model.train(dataset_train, dataset_val,

  File C:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\CNNTest2\lib\site-packages\mrcnn\model.py:2364 in train
    self.keras_model.fit(

  File C:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\CNNTest2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_v1.py:777 in fit
    return func.fit(

  File C:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\CNNTest2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_generator_v1.py:570 in fit
    return fit_generator(

  File C:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\CNNTest2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_generator_v1.py:212 in model_iteration
    batch_data = _get_next_batch(generator)

  File C:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\CNNTest2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_generator_v1.py:346 in _get_next_batch
    generator_output = next(generator)

  File C:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\CNNTest2\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py:499 in iter_sequence_infinite
    for item in seq:

  File C:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\CNNTest2\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py:485 in __iter__
    for item in (self[i] for i in range(len(self))):
```

Comment: Does it work if you try training on CPU ? If yes, then the problem is either a GPU config issue or a memory problem, 2GB is quite small.

Comment: @BenjaminBreton I suppose it also gets stuck for CPU. Also, I try the server with NVIDIA RTX A5000 (24G), and it still can't work. Do you have any ideas that may lead to this problem?

Comment: Ok, I would stick to CPU for debugging for now. Try to set the number of epochs to 100, just to see if it starts. If you don't initialize your model from scratch, it is possible that the epoch number is encoded somewhere in the model and that it prevents it from training.  Then, look at the CPU and Ram usage. If you have any stacktrace, I would add it to your question.

Comment: @BenjaminBreton Hi, I disabled my GPU temporarily, and use CPU only. Now I can get it proceed to Epoch 1/10. For now, it seems that the CPU utilization rate is low (only 2%) (Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6248R CPU). Is this normal? What I should do next?

Comment: @BenjaminBreton Just for more information, I add my traceback when I interrupt the process (cause it hangs for CPU at epoch 1/10).

Comment: Does it work if you try to run exactly the notebook in the shapes/ directory ? I would start from there, and then change the notebook to adapt the model to your need.

Comment: @BenjaminBreton No, it still hangs and occupies the memory usage. I find a link that may be the reason. Please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51176661/keras-seems-to-hang-after-call-to-fit-generator). Please tell me how you think about it, cause I am too new to deep learning to distinguish among these answers. Thanks a lot!